# Gradle 'application' plugin - is it possible to specify which mainClassName to use?

Tags: java, gradle

I want to be able to choose which `main` class I run using `gradle` at the command line using the `application` plugin.

For example, suppose I have two adjacent apps under `/src`.

I simply want to run `gradle run firstApp` or `gradle run secondApp` and have the `mainClassName` be specified by the tasks:

```
task firstApp {
  mainClassName = 'com.example.firstApp'
}

task secondApp {
  mainClassName = 'com.example.secondApp'
}
```

Is this possible?  Unfortunately, it always defaults to the secondApp in this configuration.  I am sure I am doing silly gradle mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
task firstApp(type:JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'com.example.firstApp'
}

task secondApp(type:JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'com.example.secondApp'
}
```